# `find` returns nonexistent paths

Tags: macos, find

I was trying to locate some files I suspect that I deleted (`rm -rf`) when `find` returned the following locations:

[image: terminal screenshot]

There are no such directories under `/` with these names. Is there anyone who can **dir**ect me to the right place?

I don't even know what I am looking at so I have hard time to ask the right questions maybe.

Comment: What makes you think directories don't exist?

Comment: You could try 'locate filename' and see if that gives you better information.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618) (the link leads to our sister site but the point is universal).

Answer (score 0):

#### Hypothesis

You don't see full paths because each path includes a component (directory name) that ends with a carriage return character.

E.g. if the real path was

```
/foo/bar^M/baz/qux/IMG_0283.MOV
```

where <kbd>^M</kbd> denotes the carriage return character, then it would appear as

```
/baz/qux/IMG_0283.MOV
```

because after printing `/foo/bar` the remaining part of the string is printed from the beginning of the line. It's long enough to overwrite `/foo/bar` completely.

Hence it looks as if the file was somewhere inside `/baz/`. Such directory may or may not exist, it doesn't matter. Even if it exists, the output has nothing to do with the actual `/baz/` path.

---

#### About GNU `find`

GNU `find` in my Debian 9 is immune to such tricks. When printing to a console it behaves kinda like `ls` and substitutes troublesome characters with `?`. The example path gets printed like this:

```
/foo/bar?/baz/qux/IMG_0283.MOV
```

But it's enough to pipe through `cat` (i.e. `find … | cat`) to see:

```
/baz/qux/IMG_0283.MOV
```

exactly as explained above.

I know this behavior with `?` [is not required](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), it's obviously a GNU improvement. I think `find` in macOS is [not the GNU `find`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39903571/10765659). Out of curiosity I checked the Busybox implementation of `find`, it is not immune.

Considering all these, I think my hypothesis seems at least plausible.

---

#### Solution

To reveal the real paths, pipe your original `find` command to `xxd` or some similar tool. I expect you will find a carriage return (hex `0d`) before each `/dir_`.